# If $f_n(s) \rightarrow f(s)$ for all s. Is it correct to say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\min f_n)=\min f$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, pointwise-convergence

If $f_n(s) \rightarrow f(s)$ for all $s$, is it correct to say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\min f_n)=\min f$? Are minimums of $f_n$ converging to minimum of $f$?

Answer (score 3):

No.  For example, consider the following sequence in $\mathbb{R^R}$:
$$
f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & x\leq n\\
0 & x\geq n+1\\
n+1-x & n\leq x\leq n+1
\end{cases}
$$
converging pointwise to the constant function $1$, but $\min f_n=0\not\to 1$.

Comment: You probably mean $min f_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Oops, corrected.

Comment: (+1) Ah, this is what I just suggested, but made continuous (although continuity was not stipulated, so I guess my counterexample is still okay).

Answer (score 0):

A simple counterexample is
$$
f_n(x)=[x\le n]
$$
where $[\dots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

---

An analytic counterexample is
$$
f_n(x)=e^{-x^2/n}
$$